# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ by using $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 - 1}$ and comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I've already shown that  $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 - 1} = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2(k+1)} - \frac{1}{2(k+1)}$ is convergent and tends to $\dfrac{3}{4}$.

I now must prove convergence of $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(k-1)^2}$ with this and by the help of the comparison test.

Let $a_n = \dfrac{1}{(k-1)^2} ,\; b_n =\dfrac{1}{k^2 - 1}$ but since $|a_n| \leq b_n $ is never true for any positive $k$ how I can prove that and give an upper bound?

Comment: In terms of comparison,  from k=2, compare their denominators. It becomes pretty obvious then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k^2-1 < k^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{k^2-1} > \frac{1}{k^2}\ \forall k \in \mathbb{N},\ k\geq 2$$
Therefore
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < 1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-1} = 1+\frac{3}{4} < \infty$$

Comment: "$k^2-1 < k^2$" .. don't you have to modify the sums so they have the same starting index? 

Since $\left|\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right| \leq \dfrac{1}{k^2-1}$ would be true for k > 1.
In my definition the two series have both start at $k=1$.

Comment: @rndm_me That’s why we pull the first term out of the sum. Then we have two series starting at $k=2$ and we know that one is strictly smaller than the other one and therefore finite

Comment: Ah, got it. And $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6} < 1+\dfrac{3}{4}$! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) the series converges indeed

$$\frac{\frac{1}{k^2 }}{\frac{1}{k^2 - 1}}=\frac{k^2 - 1}{k^2} \to 1$$